# Foreach loop and String in php

Tags: php, regex, string, foreach

**php Code:**

```
foreach ($html->find('table') as $noscript) {echo $data;
        echo $data;
        echo $noscript->innertext . "<br>";
    }
```

Now i need to compare every string in this with "google" it can be anything like "GOOGLE" or "Google" , here case doesn't matter.

But how do i check  `$noscript->innertext` and echo `$data;` for "google"

I am unable to think of a way to implement this. Kindly provide me some code example.

**Code i tried**

```
foreach ($html->find('table') as $noscript) {
        //if (strstr(strtolower($data)||strtolower($noscript->innertext), "google"))
        if (preg_match('/google/i', $data || $noscript->innertext)) {
            echo "This is Google";
            $real = 1;
        }


        echo $data;
        echo $noscript->innertext . "<br>";
    }
```

**Second attempt:**

```
if (strstr(strtolower($data)||strtolower($noscript->innertext), "google"))
```

Both of which are not working.

Comment: You might be looking for something called "regular expression".

Comment: Please look at my question now, edited.

Comment: `$data || $noscript->innertext` does not work in PHP (maybe you're used to javascript?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(stristr($data,'google') || stristr($noscript->innertext,'google'))
{
    echo "This is Google";
}
```

Comment: that obviously wasn't in the question

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for something called regular expression:

```
§hasGoogle = preg_match('~goo+gle~i', $text);
```

That are a language of their own to decribe strings. You find them [doucmented in the PHP manual](http://php.net/pcre.pattern) for that function above ([`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match)) and in the internet. Perhaps it's well to read a book about them as well as this is a language of it's own.

Note that this expression:

```
$data || $noscript->innertext
```

will either be `FALSE` or `TRUE` in PHP but not what you think (a string). There ain't no shortcut like this in PHP, so you need to write more code.

Comment: So you want to try if( preg_match('~~goo+gle~i', $data || $noscript->innertext)){} ?

Comment: Quite, but use `$text` instead (one variable). You can fill it earlier with your string (but debug that it contains what you thinnk it contains).

Comment: there's one `~` too much at the beginning, see as well the edit of the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463524/1376289 This works out of box, with no extra code.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($html->find('table') as $noscript) {
       if(preg_match("/^google/i", $noscript->innertext) || preg_match("/^google/i", $data)) {
          echo $data;
        }
        echo $noscript->innertext . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I need to compare $data also,